# MAMP Pro with PHP 7 OPcode caching

Tags: 8, caching

I installed Drupal 8 on MAMP Pro with PHP 7. I am getting this warning in my Drupal reports page:

> PHP OPcode caching Not enabled
>       PHP OPcode caching can improve your site's performance considerably. 
>       It is highly recommended to have OPcache installed on your server.

I looked in MAMP's PHP 7 ini file and I see this code which seems to be related to OPcode caching.

```
[OPcache]
MAMP_OPcache_MAMP
  opcache.memory_consumption=128
  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
  opcache.enable_cli=1
```

So I am not sure if I need to do anything else to enable it, it seems to be enabled based on the code above. I googled around and could not find any specific documentation with regard to MAMP and PHP OPcode caching.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. I posted the answer, but I'm not 100% sure if this is the right question to keep on DA. Moderators will decide I guess.

Comment: Yes, it may be it should be moved to Server Fault or another site.

Comment: While there is overlap with SuperUser or AskDifferent (not ServerFault), MAMP is a common tool for Drupal development, and the question stems from a Drupal warning during setup.  I think this makes is close enough to being on topic here in my eyes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just make sure that the OPCache is selected as caching mechanism in MAMP preferences.

1. Click on "Preferences".
2. Click on the "PHP" tab.
3. Select "OPcache" under "Cache" field.

[image: MAMP screenshot - PHP settings and OPcache]

Answer (score 9):

The UI is slightly different for Mamp Pro. Some may find this screenshot helpful.

[image: Mamp Pro UI differences for Opcache]

More recent versions of MAMP Pro have a different layout for the UI.

[image]

Comment: Since updating MAMP (free version) It no longer let's me apply OPcache as the PHP-Cache option. I can select and click OK, but if I edit MAMP preferences again, it' always set to off. I confirmed via CLI which php.ini was being used and ensured the php.ini was set to enable OPCache but still MAMP won't allow me to turn it on; and the Drupal installation Window warns me that it's off. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel Same problem in MAMP Pro, found a workaround I'm sure you can do a similar workaround in MAMP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74769696/mamp-pro-on-macos-cant-turn-on-opcache/74769697#74769697